# completing the square for a quartic

Tags: polynomials

Given a quartic equation in the form $x^4+bx^2+c$ it's easy to complete the square on this equation as the method is very similar to that used for square functions. But what if the quartic was of the form $x^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$. Is it possible to convert this equation to the form $(x-...)^4+b(x-...)^2+c$ or something similar, so then I can complete the square on this reduced form of the quartic.

Answer (score 1):

It's more complex than that. You can write the equation in the form $A^2-B^2=0$, but you have to determine coefficients by first solving a cubic equation. This well explained in the [following document](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEYQFjAEahUKEwiduK2r0obIAhVIORoKHdlvBKU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncl.ac.uk%2Fmaths%2Fstudents%2Fteaching%2Fnotebooks%2FEquationNotebook.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHnSUBls52ljH1SpjorXIdnb3jPUw&cad=rja) from the University of Newcastle.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can work sometimes, but not always.

Consider this:

Suppose $x^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e \equiv (x-h)^4+p(x-h)^2+q$

Then $x^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e \equiv x^4-4x^3h+6x^2h^2-4xh^3+h^4+px^2-2pxh+ph^2+q$

Coefficients of $x^3$: $b=-4h \Rightarrow h=-\frac b 4$

Coefficients of $x^2$: $c=6h^2+p \Rightarrow p=c-6h^2=c-\frac {3b^2} {8}$

Coefficients of $x$: $d=-4h^3-2ph$. Since $p$ and $h$ are already defined, this method will not work with arbitrary values of $d$.

Coefficients of $x^0$: $e=h^4+ph^2+q \Rightarrow q=e-h^4-ph^2$.